# Is the bonus mana retained after upgrading to Archangel's Staff?

Tags: league-of-legends

The item Tear of the Goddess has the UNIQUE Passive:

> Each time your Champion uses an
>   Ability their Maximum Mana will
>   increase by 4 Mana, up to a maximum of
>   twice in a six second period; bonuses
>   cap at +1000 Mana.

When you upgrade it to Archangel's Staff, do you retain the bonuses gained? Or do you have to start over?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, all bonus mana is kept, provided you are upgrading the tear into a staff, and not selling it or something crazy like that.

Comment: And the cap remains the same. I.e., if you cap the tear, the archangel's staff remains at the +1000 (Is it +1000? I know they just increased the max...) you had from the tear.